# Why there is extra blank area above my table-cell area?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
#main {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  border: 5px black solid;
}
#left {
  width: 75%;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  border: 2px red solid;
}
#right {
  width: 25%;
  display: table-cell;
  /*background-color: #000000;*/
  border: 2px green solid;
}
#photo-center {
  position: relative;
}
#large {
  width: 80%;
}
#small {
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="photo">
      <div id="photo-center">
        <img src="image/1.jpg" id="large">
        <img src="image/2.jpg" id="small">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="price">$180</td>
        <td class="buy">
          <a href="#">buy</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="price">$180</td>
        <td class="buy">
          <a href="##">buy</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="price">$180</td>
        <td class="buy">
          <a href="#">buy</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="price">$180</td>
        <td class="buy">
          <a href="#">buy</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="price">$180</td>
        <td class="buy">
          <a href="#">buy</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="price">$180</td>
        <td class="buy">
          <a href="#">buy</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why there is extra blank area above my right table-cell area and How to set large photo centre of left table-cell?

Comment: add ` vertical-align: top;` in `#right`

Answer (score 2):

i mean your css page should be like :

```
#main {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  border: 5px black solid;
}
#left {
  width: 85%;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  border: 2px red solid;
}
#right {
  width: 15%;
  display: table-cell;
  /*background-color: #000000;*/
  border: 2px green solid;
}
#photo-center {
  position: relative;
}
#large {
  width: 80%;
}
#small {
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Blank area is due to there is a `5px` border on the parent div and the padding from the `body` tag.

In order to center the large image. you have to do like this.

```
#large {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace  this css

```
#right {
    border: 2px solid green;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below demo link:

**JSFIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/DhwaniSanghvi/ntpfjpvx/

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="photo">
      <div id="photo-center">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" id="large">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" id="small">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="price">$180</td>
        <td class="buy">
          <a href="#">buy</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="price">$180</td>
        <td class="buy">
          <a href="##">buy</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="price">$180</td>
        <td class="buy">
          <a href="#">buy</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="price">$180</td>
        <td class="buy">
          <a href="#">buy</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="price">$180</td>
        <td class="buy">
          <a href="#">buy</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="price">$180</td>
        <td class="buy">
          <a href="#">buy</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
#main {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  border: 5px black solid;
}
#left {
  width: 75%;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  border: 2px red solid;
}
#right {
  width: 25%;
  display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
  /*background-color: #000000;*/
  border: 2px green solid;
}
#photo-center {
  position: relative;
}
#large {
    margin:0 auto;
}
#small {
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but your know how to make my large photo centre of right table-cell?